# OBDC connection from uipath to snowflake

Tags: connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working to connect UiPath studio to snowflake using OBDC DataSource (32bit). I have also installed snowflake driver (32-bit) for connecting purposes. But when after configuring connection, I ran the workflow, It gives the following Error.

> ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
> REST request for URL https://https://oua63383.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=8b755ace-1691-4fb6-b4c9-bfe235e0e2c2&request_guid=4662159a-53ba-4f84-8451-9cb9a375a680
> failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=6 msg='Couldn't
> resolve host name' osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have https:// twice in your URL

Comment: https:// occurred one time only I have confirmed it.

Comment: The error message that you have pasted into your question has it twice. I’m guessing the application you are using automatically adds it to the url and you have added it manually, via the config/setup, yourself